# Selenium move_to_element moving over all elements in loop

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I have written a code that logs in to LinkedIn, goes to the sales navigator page, and moves through each profile element.

The problem is coming in following lines (action.move_to_element(element).perform() to be exact) . The 'elements' contains profiles.

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//ol[@class='search-results__result-list']/li")
for element in elements:
    action.move_to_element(element).perform()
```

The action.move_to_element is not exactly going where it should go. i.e For the fourth element, instead of moving to the fourth element, it will move over the first four elements one by one. Similarly, for the fifth element, it will move over the first five elements one by one.  And so on for others.

Here's the full code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Program Files (x86)\\chromedriver.exe')

driver.get('https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login')
elementID = driver.find_element_by_id('username')
elementID.send_keys('')
elementID = driver.find_element_by_id('password')
elementID.send_keys('')
elementID.submit()

url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/sales/search/people?doFetchHeroCard=false&geoIncluded=103644278&logHistory=true&page=1&rsLogId=757633298&searchSessionId=5LvWxKggSSC4Ozevq4%2BRCg%3D%3D&titleIncluded=%2522Real%2520Estate%2520Agent%2522%2520NOT%2520%2522%2520Licensed%2522&titleTimeScope=CURRENT'
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(3)

action =  ActionChains(driver)
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//ol[@class='search-results__result-list']/li")
for element in elements:
    action.move_to_element(element).perform()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its because you are adding a new move_to_element action to your ActionChain and then executing the whole chain each iteration. You need to perform() it all at once after the loop (or make a new ActionChain every time).

```py
for element in elements:
    action.move_to_element(element)
action.perform()
```